# How to find and replace a string in a page content?

Tags: jquery, string, replace

How to find: `<link href="something.domain.name/thing">` (actually this part is not a big issue) and replace "something" with my string using jQuery ?

What I want to achieve is change link dynamically while the page is loaded.

(Why people down voting posts, don't get it)
:(
Thanx a lot

Comment: Please revise your question and provide the code that is not working for you, so that someone in SO can see if they can spot the problem.

Comment: You need to make it clear what you are trying to do. By the time jquery is loaded and executed, most links have already done what they needed to do.

Comment: @RobertA. did you solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr("href").replace("something", "something2")` like following.

```js
var href = $("#yourlink").attr("href").replace("something", "something2") 
$("#yourlink").attr("href", href); 
console.log($("#yourlink").attr("href"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="yourlink" href="something.domain.name/thing">link</a>
```

Comment: Your welcome :) please Let me now that whether it works

Comment: your welcome:), if it worked for you , please consider to accept the answer to help people understand problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need jquery for this.
To change the href of your link you can do something like this:

```
var linkToBeChanged = document.getElementById('whateverIdOrClassEtc');
linkToBeChanged.setAttribute('href', '#newvalue');
```

If you need to know the value of the href to determine your new value:

```
document.getElementById("whateverIdOrClassEtc").getAttribute("href")
```

This should allow you to set the link to whatever you want.